# android How to set image chosen to input type='file' in webview

Tags: android, webview

I try to open file or image with  on webview.
My android version is 4.4.2 so some of the methods does not work anymore.
I found linking: https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser but i don't know how to implement it, may be i need the full project.

After working for a day, i plan to detect the button and use intent to open the file. My problem is after choosing the file, it's not attach to the button type='file'

my android code is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Get webview 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    // Define url that will open in webview 
    String webViewUrl = "http://leafy-sunrise-86906.appspot.com/";

 // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Other webview options
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

    WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
        @JavascriptInterface 
      public void performClick()
      {
        // Deal with a click on the OK button
        Log.d("OpenFile", "Success");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);

      }
    }, "openfile");
}

private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri _uri = data.getData();

        //User had pick an image.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(_uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Link to the image
        final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

and web

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="fileinput" onclick="openfile.performClick();"/>
```

After choosing the file, How to attach it to button. Or any good idea.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendJavaScript. This will go something like this. In your activity result add this code :

```
cursor.close();
sendJavascript("getResult('"+imageFilePath+"')");
```

then in your web, just add the javascript method for get the result.

```
function getResult(path){
  document.getElementById("fileInput").value = path;
}
```

But you should know, the input type file cannot add the value attribute dynamically due to security reason, so you should use input type text to just save the image path.